# Where are the entrances to all the set dungeons?

Tags: diablo-iii

Patch 2.4 added set dungeons, and the entrances to those dungeons are scattered all over the map. I found a bunch of video guides online on how to find all the dungeons but those are long and tedious - does anyone have a simple list, preferably with screenshots, of all the set dungeon entrances?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From [this forum post](http://www.diablofans.com/forums/diablo-iii-general-forums/diablo-iii-general-discussion/139000-set-dungeons-complete-list-of-locations-w-video) on diablofan.com by [jhow4](http://www.diablofans.com/members/292836-jhow4): (the original post also has a video guide)

> **Barbarian:**
>
> - Immortal King's Call - A3 Ruins of Sescheron: Walk northwest and just inside the ruins take a right turn.
> - Might of the Earth - A2 City of Caldeum: Take the WP and fight through the enemies towards Belial. To the right of the entry the
>     dungeon will open.
> - Raekor's - A5 Overgrown Ruins: Walk to the right of the Survivor's Enclave and go out. Follow the path and just before a set of arches on
>     the left the dungeon will open.
> - Wrath of the Wastes - A5 Pandemonium Fortress Level 1: Go to the waypoint and walk down and back. Make your way up the stairs and at
>     the very top after a few flights will be the dungeon.
>
> **Crusader:**
>
> - Akkhan's - A3 Bastion's Keep Stronghold: At the bottom right you will go down into The Armory. Inside here simply walk to the bottom of
>     the Armory and here you will find it.
> - Invoker - A1 Tristram: Walk out of town towards Outlook Road, which is the path when you first start the game. Walk up the path and as you
>     near the very beginning there will be a small nook at the bottom where
>     you will find the dungeon.
> - Seeker of the Light - A2 Ancient Waterway: Take the Ancient Waterway WP and then enter the Waterlogged Passage. Walk all the way down and
>     before the next exit it will be on the right.
> - Roland's Legacy - A2 Road to Alcarnus: Take the WP and follow the path to the left to where it's a dead end. At the very end of the path
>     it will be at the end here.
>
> **Demon Hunter:**
>
> - Marauder's - A3 Bridge of Korsikk: Take the Korsikk WP and work your way to the middle of the map. This is located where the large
>     trebuchet is during the campaign where the short bridge hangs over the
>     lava.
> - Natalya's Vengeance - A1 Wortham Chapel Cellar: Walk outside the cellar and directly outside will be the set dungeon.
> - Shadow's Mantle - A5 Pandemonium Fortress Level 3: This is a bit of a hike. Take the Pandemonium Fortress Level 2 WP and make your way all
>     the way to the end of the map where you go to fight Malthael. Right
>     inside of level 3 the dungeon will show up.
> - Unhallowed Eessence - A2 Howling Plateau: You can take the WP to the Howling Plateau or walk through the Caldeum Bazaar. If you take the
>     Plateau then walk south through the canyon and before it hooks back to
>     the left you will find it in the bottom right corner of the map.
>
> **Monk:**
>
> - Inna's Mantra - A2 Caldeum Bazaar: Take the portal from the Hidden Camp at the north to the Bazaar. Walk into town and take a left when
>     you get inside where the Flooded Causeway.
> - Sunwuko - A4 Pinnacle of Heaven: Fight your way through the Silver Spire Level 2 to access the Pinnacle of Heaven. Before Diablo's
>     entrance go to the left to find the dungeon.
> - Raiment of a Thousand Storms - A1 Old Ruins. Simply take the way point and walk northwest. Within just a few steps at the top the
>     dungeon will show up.
> - Uliana's Strategem - A5 Zakarum Cathedral. Walk north in the Survivor's Enclave to the large cathedral at the top of the map. Walk
>     inside and at the top left is where you will find it.
>
> **Witch Doctor:**
>
> - Helltooth Harness - A1 The Royal Crypts: Fight your way through the crypts and just before you enter the room to fight Leoric you will
>     find the dungeon just inside the caged area at the north end right
>     beside the door.
> - Spirit of Arachyr - A2 Dahlgur Oasis: Probably the most difficult one, this will be at the left of the map. There is a small nook that
>     will be the same every time. The video showcases what it looks like
>     for reference.
> - Jade Harvester - A4 Vestibule of Light: Simply take the Gardens of Hope 1st tier WP and walk straight down. This will take you back to
>     the Vestibule. Once you're there walk your way down the stairs and
>     back to the beginning. At the far back right of the map you will find
>     the dungeon.
> - Zunimassa's Haunt - A3 Core of Arreat: Take the Core WP and make your way up the map. Where the map turns to the right this will be on
>     the far left in the corner.
>
> **Wizard:**
>
> - Firebird's Finery - A2 Desolate Sands: To make this easy, simply take the Archives of Zultan Kulle WP and go backwards to the entrance.
>     Here you will find the portal to the Desolate Sands. Make your way
>     just across the bridge and at the top you will find the dungeon.
> - Delsere's - A3 Skycrown Battlements: Walk right outside of the Bastion's Keep Stronghold and take the portal to Skycrown. Make your
>     way down the far right side of the map and in the back corner the
>     dungeon will be there.
> - Vyr's - A3 Rakkis Crossing: This is at the very end of Rakkis Cross before you get to Siegebreaker. If you have an Aether Walker you will
>     save yourself a lot of time to get to the end. Take the top left
>     staircase to find the dungeon at the end.
> - Tal Rasha's - A1 Old Tristram Road: Simply take the Old Ruins WP and follow the path to the northeast. Take this path all the way around
>     and when you are near the place on the left where there is a lower
>     entry area and bodies are hanging you will find this in the bottom
>     left of the map after making your way around.

Comment: what about the druid?

Comment: I believe you're talking about Diablo 2?

Comment: just wishful thinking ;)

Comment: Thanks! Though this looks like it's quoted verbatim from http://www.diablofans.com/forums/diablo-iii-general-forums/diablo-iii-general-discussion/139000-set-dungeons-complete-list-of-locations-w-video, so (1) thanks for pointing this to me but (2) you should probably source and attribute this :-)

Comment: @Oak Good point. I cited the source in the beginning of the post for you :)